# PostgreSQL - sort by UUID version 1 timestamp

Tags: postgresql, sorting, timestamp, uuid

I am using [UUID version 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_1_(date-time_and_MAC_address)) as the primary key. I would like to sort on UUID v1 timestamp. Right now if I do something like this:

```
SELECT id, title 
FROM table 
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

PostgreSQL does not sort records by UUID timestamp, but by UUID string representation, which ends up with unexpected sorting result in my case.

Am I missing something, or there is not a built in way to do this in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Did you tried something like this? `select id::timestamp, title from table order by id::timestamp desc`

Comment: that gives me an error. ERROR:  cannot cast type uuid to timestamp

Comment: Is it compulsory to use `uuid v1` ? I have tried `uuid_generate_v4` and simply tried your query it works fine.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The timestamp is one of the parts of a v1 UUID. It is stored in hex format as hundreds nanoseconds since `1582-10-15 00:00`. This function extracts the timestamp:

```
create or replace function uuid_v1_timestamp (_uuid uuid)
returns timestamp with time zone as $$

    select
        to_timestamp(
            (
                ('x' || lpad(h, 16, '0'))::bit(64)::bigint::double precision -
                122192928000000000
            ) / 10000000
        )
    from (
        select
            substring (u from 16 for 3) ||
            substring (u from 10 for 4) ||
            substring (u from 1 for 8) as h
        from (values (_uuid::text)) s (u)
    ) s
    ;

$$ language sql immutable;

select uuid_v1_timestamp(uuid_generate_v1());
       uuid_v1_timestamp       
-------------------------------
 2016-06-16 12:17:39.261338+00
```

`122192928000000000` is the interval between the start of the Gregorian calendar and the Unix timestamp.

In your query:

```
select id, title
from t
order by uuid_v1_timestamp(id) desc
```

To improve performance an index can be created on that:

```
create index uuid_timestamp_ndx on t (uuid_v1_timestamp(id));
```

Comment: And if you would like to just order by the "raw" timestamp (and not care about converting it to unix epoch timestamp) ?