# how does ordering by UUID work in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, sql-order-by, uuid, postgresql-9.4

Is there any ordering guarantee on using uuid_generate_v1() on postgresql?

If yes,tThe guarantees are per machine or it does not matter on which machine the UUID was generated? Since V1 UUID is by timestamp + MAC address, does Postgres internally order by the timestamp part and then by MAC?

Can I "order by" an UUID type column and expect it to always work (seems to work)?

I want to generate UUIDs on multiple machines (with postgresql uuid_generate_v1()), copy them to one Postgres instance and then order by the UUID column. It must guarantee order by machine, not the order of the UUIDs of all machines.

Comment: The timestamp can be extracted from the UUID (v1). Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37713131/postgresql-sort-by-uuid-v1-timestamp

Comment: I saw it, but ordering without the proposed function on this answer also seems to work (with plain ORDER BY column). Not sure if it's machine independent.

Comment: There is no universal ordering of UUIDs (or even byte layout). However, PostgreSQL has an *implementation specific* UUID ordering, as does SQL Server (and this is not guaranteed to be the same; .NET has a different ordering that SQL Server, even though both are Microsoft creations..). Thus the PostgreSQL ordering *will be consistent*. If `uuid_generate_v1` is PgSQL index-friendly and/or is well-ordered in PgSQL based on 'time' is a specific detail.

Comment: Regardless, I can't find any technical documentation but I'd "assume" that the order is 'guaranteed' *within* PostgreSQL. Changing the order would be a *large breaking change*, and may rely on the binary-storage encoding of the UUID. If there is any reason this data may be ordered *outside* of PgSQL then .. don't rely on it D:

Answer (score 3):

I tweaked the above query for PostgreSQL

```sql
With UIDs As (--                     0 1 2 3  4 5  6 7  8 9  A B C D E F
            Select 'F' as id, cast('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000011' as uuid) as uid
    Union   Select 'E' as id, cast('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000001100' as uuid) as uid
    Union   Select 'D' as id, cast('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000110000' as uuid) as uid
    Union   Select 'C' as id, cast('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000011000000' as uuid) as uid
    Union   Select 'B' as id, cast('00000000-0000-0000-0000-001100000000' as uuid) as uid
    Union   Select 'A' as id, cast('00000000-0000-0000-0000-110000000000' as uuid) as uid
    Union   Select '9' as id, cast('00000000-0000-0000-0011-000000000000' as uuid) as uid
    Union   Select '8' as id, cast('00000000-0000-0000-1100-000000000000' as uuid) as uid
    Union   Select '7' as id, cast('00000000-0000-0011-0000-000000000000' as uuid) as uid
    Union   Select '6' as id, cast('00000000-0000-1100-0000-000000000000' as uuid) as uid
    Union   Select '5' as id, cast('00000000-0011-0000-0000-000000000000' as uuid) as uid
    Union   Select '4' as id, cast('00000000-1100-0000-0000-000000000000' as uuid) as uid
    Union   Select '3' as id, cast('00000011-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' as uuid) as uid
    Union   Select '2' as id, cast('00001100-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' as uuid) as uid
    Union   Select '1' as id, cast('00110000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' as uuid) as uid
    Union   Select '0' as id, cast('11000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' as uuid) as uid
)
Select * From UIDs Order By uid desc
```

In PostgreSQL, the sort order differs:

```
Position by highest-to-lowest value

id                                  uuid                             
 0  11000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
 1  00110000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
 2  00001100-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
 3  00000011-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
 4  00000000-1100-0000-0000-000000000000
 5  00000000-0011-0000-0000-000000000000
 6  00000000-0000-1100-0000-000000000000
 7  00000000-0000-0011-0000-000000000000
 8  00000000-0000-0000-1100-000000000000
 9  00000000-0000-0000-0011-000000000000
 A  00000000-0000-0000-0000-110000000000
 B  00000000-0000-0000-0000-001100000000
 C  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000011000000
 D  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000110000
 E  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000001100
 F  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000011
```

This means that UUIDs are *not* sorted by their time component in PostgreSQL. Internally, [PostgreSQL uses `memcmp` to sort UUIDs by their memory layout](https://doxygen.postgresql.org/uuid_8c.html#aae2aef5e86c79c563f02a5cee13d1708).

Answer (score 1):

While in no means a definitive answer - ie. "is the behavior defined across all PostgreSQL installations?," this SQL (for SQL Server) to check the ordering of each byte within a GUID. Might need some tweaks for PostgreSQL.

Generating such a mapping should allow one to see if a particular UUID structure (one of the well-defined types or otherwise) "orders in a particular way" in PostgreSQL.

```
With UIDs As (--                           0 1 2 3  4 5  6 7  8 9  A B C D E F
            Select ID = 'F', UID = cast ('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000011' as uniqueidentifier)
    Union   Select ID = 'E', UID = cast ('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000001100' as uniqueidentifier)
    Union   Select ID = 'D', UID = cast ('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000110000' as uniqueidentifier)
    Union   Select ID = 'C', UID = cast ('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000011000000' as uniqueidentifier)
    Union   Select ID = 'B', UID = cast ('00000000-0000-0000-0000-001100000000' as uniqueidentifier)
    Union   Select ID = 'A', UID = cast ('00000000-0000-0000-0000-110000000000' as uniqueidentifier)
    Union   Select ID = '9', UID = cast ('00000000-0000-0000-0011-000000000000' as uniqueidentifier)
    Union   Select ID = '8', UID = cast ('00000000-0000-0000-1100-000000000000' as uniqueidentifier)
    Union   Select ID = '7', UID = cast ('00000000-0000-0011-0000-000000000000' as uniqueidentifier)
    Union   Select ID = '6', UID = cast ('00000000-0000-1100-0000-000000000000' as uniqueidentifier)
    Union   Select ID = '5', UID = cast ('00000000-0011-0000-0000-000000000000' as uniqueidentifier)
    Union   Select ID = '4', UID = cast ('00000000-1100-0000-0000-000000000000' as uniqueidentifier)
    Union   Select ID = '3', UID = cast ('00000011-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' as uniqueidentifier)
    Union   Select ID = '2', UID = cast ('00001100-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' as uniqueidentifier)
    Union   Select ID = '1', UID = cast ('00110000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' as uniqueidentifier)
    Union   Select ID = '0', UID = cast ('11000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' as uniqueidentifier)
)
Select * From UIDs Order By UID desc
```

In SQL Server (2014, [and matches that in SQL Server 2005](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alberto_ferrari/archive/2007/08/31/how-are-guids-sorted-by-sql-server.aspx)) the *descending* ordering is:

```
Position by highest-to-lowest value:

A B C D E F | 8 9 | 7 6 | 5 4 | 3 2 1 0
```

Since SQL Server's `newsequentialid` utilizes this ordering for *index-friendly GUID generation*, the behavior will probably never change. SQL Server also has to maintain this behavior across all systems to support replication. Thus, if the question was about SQL Server I would definitely say "there is a consistent ordering of GUIDs *in* SQL Server" that absolutely can be relied upon *in* SQL Server.

However, this ordering is *different* than .NET's GUID ordering and I would not be surprised if the ordering differed in PostgreSQL. The 'flipping' differences in SQL Server are because it is following [COM GUIDs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373931(v=vs.85).aspx)'s 'Variant 2' (aka little-endian) ordering; this is done even for 'Variant 1' UUIDs. (However, it seems more arbitrary as why the groups themselves are ordered right-to-left: more Microsoft history?)

The interesting question still remains: *where/how* is this *specified* to be ordered *in* PostgreSQL? If it is not well-specified, can the implementation still be treated as a behavior axiom?

Also [see this question for more details about SQL Server's UUIDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810602/sql-server-guid-sort-algorithm-why); and tasty details for 'why' these differences exist.

Comment: For anyone came here wondered about the output from Postgresql of this script, with a little modification, the output is nicely ordered 0 1 2 3 ... F. (PostgreSQL 9.5.14 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 5.4.0 20160609, 64-bit)